# Root attempt Galaxy S8+, touch screen unresponsive at TWRP

Tags: root-access, touchscreen, touch

I'm going to try to keep this as simple as possible as I don't really know what I did wrong or how I ended up where I am now.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8+ running Android 7.0 and I decided to root it. I decided to follow this guy's instructions on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh-I4uxAmUY

I follow his steps and am bought to the "Unmodified System Partition" menu after having gone through the process of factory resetting, wiping my data and using Odin to flash twrp-3.1.0-r1_dreamlteks.

The problem is that now the touch screen is unresponsive. It does literally nothing.

I am stuck at the screen that says "Keep System Read only?" where I have to "Swipe to Unlock Modifications", but find myself unable to do so because my touch screen doesn't let me swipe!

So now I'm panicking:
Firstly, I can't get the phone to shut down. Holding the power button does nothing, even if I hold it for a full minute.
Secondly, I can't boot the phone into anything except this unresponsive TWRP thing.
Thirdly, my computer no longer recognizes my phone when I try to connect it via USB (might be unrelated?).

Is my phone just bricked now?

Can I save this rooting attempt in any way, or at least revert to the stock?

Will bringing the phone to a retailer help me in any way, or have I already broken the warranty?

**UPDATE 1:** RMarkwald has bought it to my attention that I need to revert back to stock, but I am not sure I understand how to do so from my current situation, being locked at the TWRP-screen and all. Any information on the topic in future replies is deeply appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you flashed the TWRP.img file for the S8 (dreamlte) and not the S8+ (dream2lte) based off of the device type you have, and the filename for TWRP you listed.  In the tutorial he states he's showing this on the S8, and the steps apply to the S8+, but you need the S8+'s TWRP file.  The file he provides is for the S8.  You would need to flash the TWRP from here https://dl.twrp.me/dream2lte/.  I'm not sure how you get out of that screen, wait until battery dies and try to flash back to stock...?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, how exactly do I go about getting back to stock? Like what files and what operations would I need to carry out to achieve that? I'm sorry if this is a little beyond the scope of the original question, but I'll update it to reflect my extended questioning if you feel like making an answer.

Comment: You'd need ODIN, and the stock firmware .tar.md5 files for your device/carrier, for example T-Mobile's stock set of files is 3.5 GB compressed into a .zip file, 6.1 GB when unzipped.  I was able to get mine from T-Mobile's XDA thread for the device, not sure who your carrier is exactly, you may have luck here (since yours is the Exynos version, which can have TWRP flashed) https://www.sammobile.com/2017/04/19/first-firmware-for-the-galaxy-s8-is-now-available-for-download/.

Comment: Okay, cool, I think I've tracked down a copy of such. I'm from Norway, and using Telenor so https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s8/SM-G955F/TEN/download/G955FXXU1AQDD/129156/ looks about right. Now I'll just enjoy those sweet 15 kbs for the next 3 hours. Then I just boot into recovery mode, hook up my USB, run Odin, and try to flash the monstrosity from with the zip? Thanks so much for the help mate.

Comment: You should have 6 .tar.md5 files inside of the zip, unzip the zip to get those.  They should be AP, BL, CP, CSC, HOME_CSC, USERDATA.  Boot phone to Download Mode (with phone off, hold Bixby button, Vol Down, and Power buttons together, let go once you see something happen, at warning screen hit Vol Down to continue to Download Mode), connected to computer, open ODIN, then add the files accordingly.  I've heard there's issues w/ carrier files since USERDATA is new, moved out of AP now.  Apparently waiting for a newer ODIN to accomodate...not sure if this affects Exynos variant or not...

Comment: I can't find a guide at the moment, but AP goes in AP slot, BL in BL, and so on, but the new USERDATA there isn't a location in ODIN (if your firmware has this file in the download), so I'm not sure what the solution is for this right now, until a new ODIN is leaked/available.

Comment: Good information man, good information. You're giving me some hope here! If you happen to come upon a guide I'd love you forever if you shared it. That being said, if I attempt the flashing process without knowing where to put USERDATA will I be able to try again at a later point in time? My only real goal here is to not mess anything up permanently, as I'm sure you can understand.

Comment: I hate to burden you further with a different question (you've already been more than helpful in helping me get to the bottom of my enigma) but my folder only did not include a USERDATA, but only the other files (BL, AP, CP, CSC). Would it be safe to try and flash my device with these files alone? I'm a little worried about stepping into perma-brick territory and you seem very knowledgeable on the topic.

Comment: The USERDATA must be for carriers (I use T-Mobile), I would say you are okay to flash what you've got.  Since getting the T-Mo S8, the USERDATA file is new, I never had that file either when I had my T-Mo S7 Edge.

Comment: have you been successful with proposed procedure? I have exactly the same problem that I used S8+ tar file in my S8 phone. How was the phone behavior when battery died. Did you start charging and was you able to go to download mode?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @user243446. And yes, I was. I had to let the phone die naturally from battery loss, then boot it into download mode when the battery finally needed charging again and it worked. Hope it works for you.